# Emacs - octave-mode: How to change comment character?

Tags: matlab, emacs, comments, octave

I'm using Emacs 27.1 with octave-mode 6.4.0 to edit Octave code for a class in Matlab. I'd like to change the character that octave-mode uses for comments from '## " to the Matlab standard "%% ".
When I tried this code:

```
;; Change the comment character from "##" to "% ". from
;; https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10713/how-to-change-comment-character-from-hash-to-percent-sign-for-octave-maj:
(add-hook 'octave-mode-hook
    (lambda () (progn (setq octave-comment-char ?%)
                      (setq comment-start "% ")
                      (setq comment-add 0))))
;; This starts all lines in the middle of the page. Commented out 19 Sep 2023.
```

the symbol is changed to '%' but all comments start horizontally in the middle of the page, and not at the left-hand margin as it did before, on lines without code.
I tried M-customize and searching for 'octave-comment' but didn't find anything. Searching customize for 'octave' returned many things, but nothing related to the comment character.
Can anyone help me change the comment character for octave mode, but retain the normal functionality of M-; in commenting behavior? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/15170/11) help?

Comment: Yes, I just discovered that response yesterday. Thanks for pointing it out. You can mark this question redundant with that one. or paste your comment in as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: fyi since that answer is on the emacs stackexchange and not stackoverflow, it seems it cannot be marked as a duplicate.